# how to call link_to from javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I have some specific situation, I have to initiate remote ajax call from javascript (using serial port to read rfid data) and I want to send it and get ajax response. This is what I want to call:

```
<%= link_to "evidentiraj", {:action => 'time', :id=>25}, :remote => true %>
```

I tried manually to start xmlhttp.opetn from javascript, but it does not work:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","/evidentiraj/time?id=23",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Thank you.
Dorijan

Answer (score 0):

You can run `rake routes` and look for the url you need, I think it should be something like `time_evidentiraj`. Then, in your view:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","<%= time_evidentiraj_path(@evidentiraj) %>",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thank you for replay, <%= time_evidentiraj_path(:id=>23) %> correctly translate to "/evidentiraj/time?id=23" but it is not working as I expect. Maybe the problem is in some security? In my time action, I am returning format.js, which is some javascript that refresh some divs.

Comment: Ah, then you need to specify the format too. Try using `time_evidentiraj_path(:id=>23, :format => 'js')`.